# Compare the same file in two git branch

Tags: git

I have two git branch.
I want to compare the same file in two git branch.
But I don't want to switch branch.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command to compare a single file between branches:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- myfile.test
```

Comment: And I believe branch1 and branch2 can be commitish, e.g. git diff HEAD^^^ HEAD^ -- myfile.test

Answer (score 1):

[`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) is a powerful tool that lets you compare across commits, branches, and even just what you've got changed since your last commit.

In order to compare across branches, use: `git diff first_branch second_branch -- fileInQuestion.js`

Answer (score 0):

From the [git man page:](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
    This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

Use the two different sha codes that you want to difference:

```
git diff <sha1> <sha2> -- ./path/to/file/to/compare
```

The sha commit code can be on the same branch, or not.